# Can Tensorflow models run object detection in openGL framebuffer/textures without reading back to CPU

Tags: opengl, tensorflow, framebuffer

## Background:

1. I have a pipeline that uses a series of **OpenGL** shaders to processes webcam source footage and locate a feature (it's always the same feature and there is only one feature that I am ever looking for).
2. The only thing that is read back to the CPU is 4 coordinates for the bounding box.

I am interested in training an object detection NN to see if I can get better performance/accuracy at extracting my feature from the footage.

---

## The Question:

Is it possible to run the trained model in the openGL environment (using a framebuffer/texture as input) without reading the textures back and forth from the cpu/gpu?

#### Example:

1. Run my preprocessing OpenGL shader programs
2. Feature detection model *(trained with tensorflow)* using framebuffer as the input
3. Extract the bounding box coordinates

Comment: You can share (frame)buffers between OpenCL and OpenGL and tensorflow as some experimental support for OpenCL, but I guess it's a lot of work to get it working.